# Yii2 Rest API many-to-many relationship

Tags: yii2

I have created a controller to handle api requests and return a data provider object, which Yii converts into JSON.  (This is done through Yii ActiveController.)  Now this model also contains some many-to-many relationships.  How can I include the data in the many-to-many relationship in the JSON structure?

Ex.

```
{ sportsfan: { 
    id: 1, name: 'Bob', sport: 'Football', teams: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Arsenal'}, 
        { id:2, name: 'Real Salt Lake' }
    ] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer my own question.  All I needed to do is the following.  I created the following method in my model:

```
public function fields()
{
    return ['id', 'name', 'sport', 'teams'];
}
```

Note that "id" and "sport" are attributes of the model, "name" is a getter function, "teams" is a relation.  Yii2 treats them all the same.  This is a great feature!

Answer (score 0):

There is method extraFields() for this purpose (https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/rest-resources.md#overriding-extrafields-)

```
public function extraFields()
{
    return ['teams'];
}
```